# Issue with WebView in android

Tags: android

I have the following code to display a web page. Everything in this layout was working fine but when i added the web view, the web view isn't working. Please let me know how to fix this. I also suspect that the problem is with the nesting of the web view because I tried to open the same web page using another sample app with a web view without any parent views and it worked.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
            android:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/user_profile_toolbar"
                    layout="@layout/user_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="72dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context="com.example.personal.newsfeeder.DetailActivity">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           </WebView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "isn't working" means.

Comment: the web page isn't loading. Its just showing the blank page

Comment: You need to provide the JAVA code as well..

Comment: try changing width and height of `WebView` to something like `100dp`...because I think `wrap_content` does not showing `WebView`

Answer (score 1):

`Webview` inside `ScrollView` is trouble some layout.. you can try `android:fillViewport="true"` for `NestedScrollView` and `layout_height="match_parent"` for `WebView`.. remove the unnecessary `LinearLayout` inside nestedscroll.. just use `WebView`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fillViewport="true">
```

Try also webview height change to static height.. if you want.. it might work also

make sure you use **latest android support design library**

Comment: `android:fillViewport="true" ` property is not showing up for the nestedScrollView. I am also using the support library 24.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for trying to help. I figured out the solution. It was not in the layout file at all. The link to load the web page in the line `myWebView.loadUrl("xyz")`was just empty string and I just forgot to initialize that string correctly.

But I don't think there is any issue here in my layout by using WebView inside the NestedScrollView. It works smoothly for me.

But please do let me know if its not a good practice to use WebView inside the NestedScrollView.